# Gravity Forms Slow Loading

Tags: jquery, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have created a long order form using Gravity Forms (installed on Wordpress site), with lots of conditional logic. The problem is that the page with the form is rendering very slowly, selecting/deselecting elements/fields is very slow and is very much dependant on the hardware/browser that is used to load the form.

How to fix for this issue...

Comment: I'm also facing same issue, anyone who could help?

Comment: Can you please post a link to the page in question so that a better researched answer can be given?